# Comportamiento anormal de foreach en php 7.0, repite el ultimo elemento en foreach anidado

Tags: php, array, zend, foreach

soy nuevo por aqui, y como dice el titulo el foreach se comporta de manera anormal.
Quiero es listar todos los horarios de conductor por turno (1 = dia,2 = noche), a su vez estos con los dias de lunes a viernes (0 = domingo, 1 = lunes ,etc)
Teniendo en cuenta que el conductor 1 tiene programado solo el turno 2 desde lunes hasta el viernes

Aqui mi tabla: TBL_CONDUCTOR_HORARIO

```
id  dia turno  fecha_reg  conductor_id
1    0  2    2017-12-11      1
2    2  2    2017-12-11      1
3    4  2    2017-12-11      1
4    6  2    2017-12-11      1
5    1  2    2017-12-11      1
6    3  2    2017-12-11      1
7    5  2    2017-12-11      1
```

Aqui mi codigo:

```
$turnos[] = (object)['id'=>TURNO_DIA,'title'=>'Día'];
```

```
$turnos[] = (object)['id'=>TURNO_NOCHE,'title'=>'Noche'];
```

```
$dias = [
       (object)['id'=>'0', 'name'=>'Domingo'],
       (object)['id'=>'1', 'name'=>'Lunes'],
       (object)['id'=>'2', 'name'=>'Mártes'],
       (object)['id'=>'3', 'name'=>'Miércoles'],
       (object)['id'=>'4', 'name'=>'Jueves'],
       (object)['id'=>'5', 'name'=>'Viernes'],
       (object)['id'=>'6', 'name'=>'Sábado']
       ];
```

```
foreach($turnos as $c=>$turno)
  {
    foreach($dias as $dia)
    {
       $rsHorarioTurno = (new Select())
       ->from(array('tu'=>TBL_CONDUCTOR_HORARIO))
       ->where('tu.condh_conductor_cond_id = ?', $idConductor)
       ->where('tu.condh_dia = ?', $dia->id)
       ->where('tu.condh_turno = ?', $turno->id)
       ->fetchRow();

      if($rsHorarioTurno)
      {
        $dia->checked = "checked";
      }else{
        $dia->checked = "";
      }
    }

    $turno->dias = $dias;
  }

var_dump($turnos);
```

Aqui esta el problema , los dias que agregue que si estan o no marcados, siempre salen iguales, ya sea el turno 1 o el turno 2.

Y asi me imprime:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#34 (3) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["title"]=>
    string(4) "Día"
    ["dias"]=>
    array(7) {
      [0]=>
      object(stdClass)#26 (3) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(1) "0"
        ["name"]=>
        string(7) "Domingo"
        ["checked"]=>
        string(7) "checked"
      }
      [1]=>
      object(stdClass)#27 (3) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(1) "1"
        ["name"]=>
        string(5) "Lunes"
        ["checked"]=>
        string(7) "checked"
      }
      [2]=>
      object(stdClass)#29 (3) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(1) "2"
        ["name"]=>
        string(7) "Mártes"
        ["checked"]=>
        string(7) "checked"
      }
      [3]=>
      object(stdClass)#30 (3) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(1) "3"
        ["name"]=>
        string(10) "Miércoles"
        ["checked"]=>
        string(7) "checked"
      }
      [4]=>
      object(stdClass)#31 (3) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(1) "4"
        ["name"]=>
        string(6) "Jueves"
        ["checked"]=>
        string(7) "checked"
      }
      [5]=>
      object(stdClass)#32 (3) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(1) "5"
        ["name"]=>
        string(7) "Viernes"
        ["checked"]=>
        string(7) "checked"
      }
      [6]=>
      object(stdClass)#33 (3) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(1) "6"
        ["name"]=>
        string(7) "Sábado"
        ["checked"]=>
        string(7) "checked"
      }
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#35 (3) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(2)
    ["title"]=>
    string(5) "Noche"
    ["dias"]=>
    array(7) {
      [0]=>
      object(stdClass)#26 (3) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(1) "0"
        ["name"]=>
        string(7) "Domingo"
        ["checked"]=>
        string(7) "checked"
      }
      [1]=>
      object(stdClass)#27 (3) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(1) "1"
        ["name"]=>
        string(5) "Lunes"
        ["checked"]=>
        string(7) "checked"
      }
      [2]=>
      object(stdClass)#29 (3) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(1) "2"
        ["name"]=>
        string(7) "Mártes"
        ["checked"]=>
        string(7) "checked"
      }
      [3]=>
      object(stdClass)#30 (3) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(1) "3"
        ["name"]=>
        string(10) "Miércoles"
        ["checked"]=>
        string(7) "checked"
      }
      [4]=>
      object(stdClass)#31 (3) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(1) "4"
        ["name"]=>
        string(6) "Jueves"
        ["checked"]=>
        string(7) "checked"
      }
      [5]=>
      object(stdClass)#32 (3) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(1) "5"
        ["name"]=>
        string(7) "Viernes"
        ["checked"]=>
        string(7) "checked"
      }
      [6]=>
      object(stdClass)#33 (3) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(1) "6"
        ["name"]=>
        string(7) "Sábado"
        ["checked"]=>
        string(7) "checked"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Como se puede apreciar en ambos estan iguales.
Gracias por la ayuda de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

`$turno->dias = $dias;` le asigna a `$turno->dias` el valor `$dias` que es un objeto. Cada modificación subsecuente a `$dias` afecta a todos los elementos que hacían referencia a ese objeto. Vale decir, cuando modificas el valor de `$dias` para el turno nocturno, también cambia el objeto `$dias` que habías asignado al turno diurno.

Esto consta en la [documentación](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php):

> As of PHP 5, an object variable doesn't contain the object itself as
>   value anymore. It only contains an object identifier which allows
>   object accessors to find the actual object. When an object is sent by
>   argument, returned or assigned to another variable, the different
>   variables are not aliases: they hold a copy of the identifier, which
>   **points to the same object**.

Tendrías que hacer `$turno->dias = clone $dias;`

Comment: gracias por la respuesta, lo probé y sigue sin funcionar, pero seguiré intentando con la documentacion en mano.

Answer (score 1):

Al segundo dia de presentado el problema lo resolvi, aqui dejo como lo hice:

```
foreach($turnos as $c=>$turno)
  {
    foreach($dias as $dia)
    {
       $rsHorarioTurno = (new Select())
       ->from(array('tu'=>TBL_CONDUCTOR_HORARIO))
       ->where('tu.condh_conductor_cond_id = ?', $idConductor)
       ->where('tu.condh_dia = ?', $dia->id)
       ->where('tu.condh_turno = ?', $turno->id)
       ->fetchRow();

      if($rsHorarioTurno)
      {
        $dia->checked = "checked";
      }else{
        $dia->checked = "";
      }
    }
    $tmp = serialize($dias);
    $turno->dias = unserialize($tmp);

  }
```

lo que agregue fue el

```
$tmp = serialize($dias) ;
```

[serialize](http://php.net/manual/es/function.serialize.php) y luego el

```
unserialize($tmp);
```

[unserialize](http://php.net/manual/es/function.unserialize.php)
gracias a @amenadiel que me paso la documentacion y pude encontrar esta funcion.